# How to add an undo button to a Reactive Form (Angular 2)?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have built a form using the Reactive Forms technique available in Angular 2. The form has many controls of different types. Now I need to add an undo button to it. I have been able to set up a basic undo button using the `click` and `change` events. I'm saving the previous value when someone clicks the form control and storing that value to Local Storage when the control's value is changed. However, this method has some drawbacks. For example, when someone *tabs* into the control, the `click` event would not fire.

So is there a way to save *versions* of the form when a change occurs? I think the ideal solution would be a *watcher* which will keep an eye on the form and save versions of it.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but check this example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-changes-history

I used valueChanges of the form group to push the changes in an Array, so then I can restore the changes

Comment: It's been a year since I posted that question. I was just beginning to learn Angular back then. I think I tried to use the `AbstractControl#valueChanges` method. But I couldn't utilize it because we had a custom input field that wasn't going to report its changes via that method. I didn't know how to create custom controls for Angular at that time. I will try to refactor my code with the help of your example and see how things work.

Comment: Thanks man, even after all this time your example is awesome and help a lot!