# Angular Forms - getting what changed from ValueChange

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular's Reactive Forms and I'm on the road on implementing an Undo/Redo functionality.

What I would like is to "pack" consecutive modifications on the same field into one single undo action. I think that in order to accomplish this I will need to compute some sort of delta, maybe using a diffing library (like [this](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch)).

Let me explain this with an example:

- the user changes the "name" field to "Tom"
- the user selects the "surname" field to "Cat"
- the user changes the "name" field to "Jerry", writing very slowly or exiting and entering into the field multiple times.
- the user presses Undo.

I want the Undo action to restore the "Tom" value in the "name" field, without passing through the "Jerr", "Jer" etc. values.

Is this something that can be done only attaching to form.valuechange via Observable transformations or is there some alternative better suited for the task?

I don't have any code to share, because currently I'm just studying how to implement the feature, so please, spare me the "show us what you got" mantra ;)

Thanks!

Comment: I would takle this task using the Command Pattern. Encapsulating each user-change into a command object with a "do" and "undo" method. Then you can build a stack with these commands and undo or redo an action as you like.

Comment: I think using a state would be your best bet. https://redux.js.org/recipes/implementing-undo-history Although this link is for straight Redux I'm sure the implementation is nearly identical in NgRx.

Comment: IMHO it's a little bit overkill to use redux for a simple undo task, a service could do the work easily and if you want state just use Observable. Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355194/how-to-add-an-undo-button-to-a-reactive-form-angular-2?rq=1

Comment: Redux and similar solution are, IMHO, not suitable to use with reactive forms: both (Redux and the FormGroup) are designed to be the "single source of truth". So I tend to think that putting commands on top of the form subsystem is an antipattern with a lot of redundancy. I would like to GENERATE the equivalent of the commands from the form, and not vice versa.

Comment: @Robert the solution you link is the "usual" way of doing things, which is just based on the whole form value and is not robust to array additions and other operations which are incompatible with the simple `form.setValue` call. And it doesn't address multiple changes to the same field: I would like to merge them into one single operation, but this simplistic solutions do not.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve using the rxjs operators debounce and pairswise, like

```
formControl=new FormControl('')

this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(this.fromControl.value),
    debounceTime(500),
    pairwise())
    .subscribe(([old,value])=>{
      console.log(old,value)
    })
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pn85xa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Or use only debounceTime

```
this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        .subscribe((res)=>{
          this.myLog.push(res)
        })
```

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for a way to get only the changes, and not all the form value. I think I'll have to process the form value via a diff library, to get what exactly changed in the form values.